# How to replace a string value in application target's info file

Tags: ios, info

I have added a url to my application target's info as a string.

```
BaseURL : http://sandbox.xxxx.com/xxxx
```

What I want to do is according to some results im getting after first loging, this url should be replaced with a new url coming with that service. Is it possible to replace this string value programmatically?
If so please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the url is in your NSUserDefaults, if not use your normal baseURL to login then save the new url to NSUserDefaults, then the next time it will be read from the NSUserDefaults when logging in